# Is there a way to insert a range of dates into mysql database table

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using a form for users to book accommodation for holidays via my website, booking details includes apartment, check-in, checking out dates and total days calculated using a date diff function.  I am also using a for-loop to iterate between the check-in and checking out dates which in then generates a range of dates.  The problem is, when I execute my insert query to mysql, only the end date from the range get inserted into the database table. My goal is to have the whole range inserted into mysql in order for me to disable dates already booked on the date picker.  Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong, please see my code below.

I have already tried using the date period object and have explored all the data types for the date range field in phpmyadmin.

I also tried using a separate table for the date range

```
if(isset($_POST['apmt'])){

$value = $_POST['apmt'];
$ds = $_POST['ds'];
$de = $_POST['de'];
$d = $_POST['d'];


 try{ 
$dateb = $de;
$datea = $ds;

  for ($i = $datea; $i <= $dateb; $i++)
  {
          $dr = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i));
  }  


$query = "INSERT INTO bookings SET apmt = :apmt, dateStart = :dateStart, dateEnd = :dateEnd, dateRange = :dateRange, totalDays = :totalDays, date = NOW(), clientID = '".$_SESSION['ID']."' ";
$s = $pdo->prepare($query);
$s->bindvalue(":apmt", $value);
$s->bindvalue(":dateStart", $ds);
$s->bindvalue(":dateEnd", $de);
$s->bindvalue(":dateRange", $dr);
$s->bindvalue(":totalDays", $d);
$s->execute();

$id = $pdo->lastInsertId();

if($id > 0 ){

    $table = "";
    $table .= '<table style="text-align:center;width:100%;margin:auto"><tr><th>APARTMENT</th><th>DATE START</th><th>DATE END</th><th>DAYS</th></tr>';
    $table .= '<tr><td>' .$value. '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' .$ds. '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' .$de. '</td>';
    $table .= '<td>' .$d. '</td>';
    $table .= '</tr></table>';
    echo $table ."</br>";

}

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
  $output = "Unable to connect to database server" . $e->getMessage();
  echo "$output";
  exit();   
}

}
```

Comment: it would help if you included your table schema

Comment: and if you give us some examples and expected results

Answer (score 1):

So, the problem you defined comes from your `for` loop giving unexpected results, you're re-assigning the value of `$br` after each iteration which is why at the completion of your loop, you have the last date stored in `$br`.

I'd recommend the following solution since it'll be the easiest to manipulate later on and give you the cleanest code. By replacing `$br` with an **Array**, you can append an item to it after each iteration. When inserting into your database, using the **[implode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)** function will let you stringify it in the way you want without using hacky string manipulation.

```
$dr = [];
for ($i = $datea; $i <= $dateb; $i++)
{
    array_push($dr, date("Y-m-d", strtotime($i)));
}
```

Now, when you go to insert into your table, reference the array as follows:

```
$drString = implode(',', $dr) # (String) "date,date,date,date"
```

### Further advice

In the case that you are using the SQL Date schema as slightly hinted in the question, storing ranges isn't default for them. So storing as a **Text** or **Varchar** may be your best option, then *iterating through the range string ("date,date,date") and creating a new **Date** PHP object for each exploded string individually.*

Comment: Thanks, @user3035660, means a lot. Would you consider choosing this answer? :)

Comment: Thanks, @user3035660